# How to make array of UIViews perform selector

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an NSArray of UIViews,

```
NSArray *someViews;
```

I can make them perform a selector like this:

```
[someViews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:someColor];
```

I want to make them perform a selector that takes a struct parameter like a CGAffineTransformIdentity

Simply boxing the transform in an NSValue doesn't work:

```
NSValue *someTransform = [NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[someViews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(setTransform:) withObject:someTransform];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way is probably just to use a `for` loop here:

```
for (UIView *view in someViews)
    [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
```

Comment: I agree the loop method simply works. Just for my information, is it categorically impossible to call methods with struct parameters?

Comment: With a `performSelector:` sort of route, yes, I believe that is just impossible.

Comment: What would you guess that -performSelector:withObject: does, anyhow? It's a good bet that the code looks very similar to nil's code above. If you really need to send a struct using a -performSelector: type of message, create a category on NSArray and add a -performSelector:withStruct: method.